# libgdx Bullet 3D and Rolling Friction causing NaN

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, bullet

I am trying to use gdx-bullet for some general simulation.
More specifically, I am trying to set the rolling friction of a sphere as it rolls off an inclined plane.

I set the sphere's rolling friction to non-zero.  I position it above the inclined plane. The sphere falls until it hits the plane, at which point it should roll down the plane.  However, instead, the matrix is replaced with all NaNs (except the last row):

```
Step 36
[1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0]
[0.0|1.0|0.0|0.0]
[0.0|0.0|1.0|2.0862775]
[0.0|0.0|0.0|1.0]

Step 37
[NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN]
[NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN]
[NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN]
[0.0|0.0|0.0|1.0]
```

Executable example code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Quaternion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.Bullet;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btBoxShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btCollisionDispatcher;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btCollisionShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btDbvtBroadphase;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btDefaultCollisionConfiguration;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btSphereShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.dynamics.btDiscreteDynamicsWorld;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.dynamics.btRigidBody;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.dynamics.btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.linearmath.btMotionState;


public class TestRollingFriction {

    private static class BasicMotion extends btMotionState
    {
        Matrix4 m4 = new Matrix4();

        @Override
        public void setWorldTransform(Matrix4 transform) {
            m4.set(transform);
        }

        @Override
        public void getWorldTransform(Matrix4 transform) {
            transform.set(m4);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return m4.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Bullet.init();

        btDefaultCollisionConfiguration collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
        btCollisionDispatcher dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
        btDbvtBroadphase broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();
        btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
        btDiscreteDynamicsWorld collisionWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfiguration);
        collisionWorld.setGravity(new Vector3(0, 0, -9.8f));

        // Create a box at the origin, of size 1,1,1
        btCollisionShape boxShape = new btBoxShape(new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
        // Rotate it by 20 degrees about the y axis so that the sphere will roll off it
        btMotionState boxMotion = new BasicMotion();
        Quaternion q = new Quaternion(new Vector3(0,1,0),20);
        boxMotion.setWorldTransform(new Matrix4(q));

        // Print out the box's matrix
        System.out.println(boxMotion);

        btRigidBody boxBody = new btRigidBody(0, boxMotion, boxShape);
        boxBody.setFriction(2);
        boxBody.setRollingFriction(0.2f);
        collisionWorld.addRigidBody(boxBody);

        btCollisionShape sphereShape = new btSphereShape(1);
        btMotionState sphereMotion = new BasicMotion();

        // Set the sphere's position, rotation, and scale
        Matrix4 tempM2 = new Matrix4(new Vector3(0, 0, 4), new Quaternion(), new Vector3(1,1,1));
        sphereMotion.setWorldTransform(tempM2);
        btRigidBody sphereBody = new btRigidBody(3, sphereMotion, sphereShape);

        // Does not matter what I put in here; 
                // If it's non-zero, then the matrix ends up with NaN in it.
        sphereBody.setRollingFriction(0.2f);
        sphereBody.setFriction(2);

        collisionWorld.addRigidBody(sphereBody);

        int count = 0;      
        while(count < 100)
        {
            collisionWorld.stepSimulation(0.05f);

            System.out.println(count);
            System.out.println(sphereMotion);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the same result running on both Android and Linux Desktop.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what was going wrong.
Essentially, I:

- Enabled ball's rolling friction
- Set the ball's localInteria to zero

To fix the problem, I needed to call

```
Vector3 localInertia = new Vector3();
float mass=1;
// Calculate the inertia of the sphere, with mass=1,
// and store it into 'localInertia'
sphereShape.calculateLocalInertia(mass, localInerertia);

btRigidBody sphereBody = new btRigidBody(mass, sphereMotion, sphereShape, localInertia);
```

Once I added the call to get the local inertia, and then added it to the rigid body, it started working properly.